# Admin: sub menu doesnt display under apperance when activate my themes

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, admin-menu, sub-menu

I got a strange issue in WordPress. I build a themes for WordPress. when I activate my theme, some sub-menu under appearance in admin panel where missing.

[image]

If I activate another themes it works normal.

[image]
I comment out some lines in themes but no progress. What makes this problem and How to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you add these subpages to when you created your theme? As far as I know these are custom theme options that need to be built into the theme as [submenus](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of those are controlled by your theme support. The functionality does not come for "free" with WordPress, you need to implement the actual code. Once you have put together the code for your theme to support one of the features you can enable it with [`add_theme_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support).

for example, in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function () {
  add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
} );
```

This would trigger the display of the "Background" menu item in the Appearance sidebar, but it would not affect your theme, you would need to hook into it and implement the [theme features](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Features).